# Is there a way to markup webpages on the S3?

Tags: browser

In the stock browser or in Chrome, is there a way to markup webpages in different colours for notes etc.? It would be good if the marks show up everytime I open that webpage. If that's not possible, I could save it as an image.

OS: 4.1.1
Samsung Galaxy S3

Comment: You want to alter and adjust how your web page looks like, when the website is accessed from a mobile device (e.g. S3), correct?

Comment: @Sid He's probably looking for something like marker.to Unfortunately, I haven't seen any mobile browser with anything like that. Firefox and Chrome doesn't seem to support add-ons yet (in my case).

Comment: Saving as an image is probably the best bet for now.

Comment: @geffchang, I came across an app which seems fine. Hope this is what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After giving thought to [what geffchang said](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/48730/is-there-a-way-to-markup-webpages-on-the-s3#comment65699_48730) above, I came across with the app **[Skitch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evernote.skitch&hl=en)** which can be used to highlight webpages as you wish.

Added advantage for this app is you can directly synchronize your work with Evernote, a widely used note-taking app.

Comment: I use Evernote too!! Can Skitch mark up webpages in real-time?

Comment: @verve, For the best of my knowledge, you have to take a snapshot first. The best thing is that you can share a web page directly from your browser.

Comment: Share a page directly from the browser?  How?

Comment: Which menu button?  In the Skitch app?

Comment: @verve Open the browser => Go to the web page => Click Menu button => Share => Select Skitch.

Comment: What is considered the menu button?  In the stock or Chrome?

Comment: [This image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4tmrQ.jpg) shows what the menu button is

Comment: Don't. We all learnt at some point. Happy to help. :)